# Enum for error codes

Tags: java, error-handling, enums

I'm writting a client-server application. Now I'm just doing error handling. If a error occurs at the server (after a request from the client), the server should create an error object, serialize it and send it to the client.

In the error object I have a field for the error code. Of course I could place an enum in this object listing all possible error I want to cover, but then the serialized object gets to big.

Thus, I'm thinking about writting an external enum class available for the server and the client and only sending the error code from the server to the client.

Would this be a good idea?

If the client receives such an error code how can he then look up the corresponding enum in the enum class?

Comment: The question is: does it ever happen that the error has some information attached? Examples are the input that made it fail, a session id, an incident id. Otherwise yes, either enum or error code is an okay idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send the error code that you defined in your enum:

```
public enum ErrorCode {
    OK(0), KO(1);
    // ...
}

public class Error implements Serializable {
    private int code;
    private String message;
    // ...
}

public void myMethod() {
    // ...
    // something went bad!
    InternalError ie = getMyInternalErrorSomehow();
    Error error = new Error(ie.getErrorCode().getCode(), 
              "something bad happened and i am sending you a nice message");
    client.send(error);
}
```